# How to "catch" a object has no attribute in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i got the following code and what i am trying is to see what they are now playing or what they stopped playing and make stats out of that in the Server, like: "Rainbow Six currently playing: 8". But that doenst work, when the script gets an error and closes the "loop".

```
if before.activity != after.activity:

    #Stats for Rainbow
    afteractivity_name = str(after.activity.name) if after.activity.name else None

    #When someone started playing
    if afteractivity_name == "Rainbow Six Siege":

        #Getting the current amount and setting variables
        rainbow_stats = await bot.fetch_channel(971830717292101722)
        rainbow_stats_str = str(rainbow_stats)
        rainbow_stats_split = rainbow_stats_str.split(" ")
        last_count = rainbow_stats_split[3]
        last_count = int(last_count)

        #Making and setting the new one
        new_count = last_count + 1
        await rainbow_stats.edit(name=f"\U0001F4CA Currently Playing: {new_count}" )
```

Error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\.1 Bot Test\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\.1 Bot Test\Bot\Bot Skript.py", line 459, in on_member_update
    beforeactivity_name = str(before.activity.name) if after.activity.name else None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: The only thing that is obvious is that `after.activity` is `None`; we have no idea why it is though, so your [mre] needs to include enough info so we know why. Otherwise we can't really help you beyond wild guesses.

Comment: Did you try to check explicitly whether `before.activity` and/or `after.activity` `is None` before doing the rest of the logic? When it is, *what should happen*? If you think about these questions, are you now able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```py
afteractivity_name = str(after.activity.name) if after.activity.name else None
```

doesn't actually do what you want it to do.

You want to set `afteractivity_name` to the name, if it exists, otherwise if `after.activity` is `None`, set it to `None`.

However, you access `after.activity.name` already, when evaluating the condition. This will cause the error because you're trying to get `name` attribute of `None`

Instead, try

```py
afteractivity_name = str(after.activity.name) if (after.activity is not None) and (after.activity.name is not None) else None
```

This will check if `after.activity` is `None` before trying to access `name`.

It's also better to explicitly check that it is not `None`, rather than just testing the truthyness, which could potentially be `False` depending on how the library calculates it.